# how to add custom headers to httpRequest in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying make an `http get()` request by passing some `values` in `headers`, Now i am replacing the `headers` like this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ICustomer} from 'src/app/models/app-models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {
private baseUrl = '....api url....';
public authKey = '....auth_key......';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public async AllCustomers(): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
   const apiUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/customers`;

   return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(apiUrl ,
    {headers: new HttpHeaders({Authorization: this.authKey})}).toPromise();<=====
  }

}
```

When i replace the headers like this:

`headers: new HttpHeaders({Authorization: this.authKey})`

The default headers values(i,e Content-Type : application/json) will be replaced by the above headers.

[image]
Instead of replacing the headers how can i add `custom headers`, I tried like this:

```
  public async AllCustomers(): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
    const apiUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/courses`;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authKey);
    headers.append('x-Flatten', 'true');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }
```

What's wrong with my approach, I am new to `angular`, Any help?

Comment: If you want to send auth token why don't you use an http interceptor ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should add header to your get request like this. Also since HttpHeaders is immutable object you have to reassign header object

```
  public async AllCustomers(): Promise<ICourses[]> {
    const apiUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/courses`;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', this.authKey);
    headers = headers.append('x-Flatten', 'true');
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.get<ICourses[]>(apiUrl, {headers}).toPromise();
  }
```

Comment: I have added `header` to get request as you told. Got this error `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized","url"`

Comment: Then your auth key is wrong. Check your auth key again

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add headers object in request

From

```
return this.http.get<ICourses[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
```

To

```
return this.http.get<ICourses[]>(apiUrl, { headers }).toPromise();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 

}


public getHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this._auth.token}`
  });
  return headers;
}


public getData() {
  const url     = `https://stackoverflow.com/api/test`;
  const body    = { };
  const options = { headers: this.getHeaders() };
  return this._http.post<any>(url, body, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 15, below code works (thanks to George C.)

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({'customHeader', 'customHeaderValue'});

return this.http.post<any>(BaseUrl + 'api/endpoint', formData, { headers: headers, observe: 'response' })
```

However below code sample only does lazy updates.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('customHeader': 'customHeaderValue');
return this.http.post<any>(BaseUrl + 'api/endpoint', formData, { headers: headers, observe: 'response' })
```